# RPi2 OSMC Transmission NFS Permissions error

Tags: permissions, nfs, transmission, osmc

I'm having trouble with transmission accessing my NFS share, giving a "permission denied" error. I'm using the most recent OSMC on RPi 2, with the transmission app as downloaded through the osmc app store.

I've done some research, but have hit something of a wall. I believe transmission is running under the osmc user (Not enough reputation to post pictures but link is to result of `ps alx | grep trans`)

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrJA1.png)

Here's my systemd transmission.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
After=udisks-glue.service

[Service]  
User=osmc  
Group=osmc  
Type=notify  
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10  
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error --allowed *.*.*.*  

[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Transmission can save to the SD card without issue, so it must be something to do with the NFS. The drive mounts on boot to `/home/osmc/NFS`, and I can access, write to and delete from the drive from the osmc user through both SSH the UI so it looks like the drive is mounting fine.

This is my fstab file, I cannibalised it from a few different sites but unfortunately this was several months ago and I can't remember where most of it came from. I remember the point of it was to delay the mounting until after the network started, but that's about it.

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot    vfat     defaults,noatime    0   0
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /    ext4      defaults,noatime    0   0
//192.168.2.1/volume(sda1) /home/osmc/NFS cifs noauto,x-systemd.automount,guest,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Not sure what else would be useful to know, if anyone could point me in a useful direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like there's something strange going on with the version of transmission you download through the OSMC app store - I uninstalled with `sudo apt-get purge armv7-transmission-app-osmc` then reinstalled with `sudo apt-get install armv7-transmission-app-osmc` and all seems fine.

Hope this saves someone from the days of googling that I've had to do.